# Why does virtual not call the overridden function here?

Tags: c++, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
struct MemA { virtual void tellClass() { std::cout << "I am member of class A" << std::endl; } };
struct MemB : public MemA { void tellClass() { std::cout << "I am member of class B" << std::endl; } };

class A {
    MemA *current;
public:
    A() : current(new MemA()) {}
    void getMemClass() { current->tellClass(); }
    ~A() { delete current; }
};
class B : public A {
    MemB *current;
public:
    B() : A(), current(new MemB()) {}
    ~B() { delete current; }
};

void main() { B().getMemClass(); }
```

In the above program I have declared the `tellClass()` function as virtual which means it should decide which function to call at runtime. Despite that it is printing "I am member of class A" even though I am calling `getMemClass()` from a class B object which has hidden the `MemA *current` with `MemB *current` during inheritence.

How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: `getMemClass()` is a member of `A`, that means `current->tellClass()` is using `A`'s `current->tellClass()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is the only way to resolve this kind of issue overridding the whole function into class B thus violating the DRY principle a little bit? Is there any smarter approach?

Comment: *"which has hidden the `MemA *current` with `MemB *current` during inheritence."* -- "Hidden" does not mean "replaced". Data members do not act virtually.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want there to be two "current" objects (a current MemA and a current MemB)? Or do you want there to be one "current" object which could be either a MemA or a MemB?

Comment: if `struct MemA` and `struct MemB` switch, I mean if base and derived swtich then your claim will occur and be correct

Comment: @RaymondChen Ideally I want there to be 1 "current" object. But since I am inheritting from A then I cannot get rid of the parent class object right? As soon as I call the parent class method then it will by default refer to the parent class "current" object.

Comment: You can have the parent class and the derived class share the `current` object. A's constructor would be `A(MemA* initial = new MemA()) : current(initial) {}`, and B's constructor would be `B() : A(new MemB()) {}`  You'll also have to make `MemA`'s destructor virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current` in `A` is a different member from the `current` in `B`, i.e. there are two members `A::current` and `B::current`. `B` has both of them as member.

The former is only hidden in as so far as naming `current` *unqualified in the context of class `B`* refers to `B::current` instead of `A::current`. In the context of class `A` (where you are evaluating the call `current->tellClass();`) the unqualified name still refers to the `A::current` member.

Data members in C++ cannot be overridden in the same sense as (virtual) member functions can.

The `A::current` member of your `B` object is pointing to a `MemA` complete object, not a `MemB` object.

Comment: Is there any smart way of calling the MemB current member if the object is of B class without overriding the whole method in class B?

Comment: @ChandramouliMukherjee No, but is there a reason to have both members? Isn't just `A::current` enough? You can pass the `new B()` as a pointer to a base class constructor to store in `A::current`.

Comment: why would you do that? you can store the object in A::current and in class b use static_cast<MemB*> since you know it is of that type...

Comment: @user17732522 I like your idea of passing the `new B()` object as a pointer. I did not think of that. That should work perfectly. Thanks :)